# Customer's information not found with Customer's id getting 404 not found even though I am passing the parameter carRentalId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
let carRentalInfo = require('../models/carRental-model.js');

var infocar = {
            userName: req.body.userName, 
            password: req.body.password,
            email:req.body.email,
            firstName:req.body.firstName,
            lastName:req.body.lastName
        };
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    carRentalInfo.findById(req.params)
    .then(infocar => {
        console.log("yelo!!!",infocar)
        if(!infocar) {
            console.log("yelo!!!",infocar)
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "customer's information not found for Customer's id " + req.params.carRentalId
            });            
        }
        res.send(infocar);
    }).catch(err => {
            if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Customer's information not found with Customer's id " + req.params.carRentalId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Error retrieving Customer's information with customer's id " + req.params.carRentalId
        });
    });
};
```

Always getting 404 error with the message Customer's information not found with Customer's id  even after passing carRentalId as parameter. I was trying to populate customer's information based on carRentalId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass id only in case if you use findById method. But you're passing all the request params. To make it work you just need to change your model call this way:

```
carRentalInfo.findById(req.params.id)
```

Comment: do you mean exactly this carRentalInfo.findById(req.params.id)     It's not working and I am still getting 404 error @Sasha

Comment: yes I do. req.params should have "id" property in case if you're passing id in your request as a parameter.

Comment: It doesn't work. Although I can understand that I need to change it to carRentalInfo.findById(req.params.id)... There is something else due to which I am still getting 404 error  @Sasha

Comment: You need to provide the code for carRental-model.js. Otherwise it's hard to tell what is the actual problem

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const carRentalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userName:{type: String},        
    password: {type:String},
    email:      {type: String},
    firstName:  {type: String},
     lastName:   {type: String}
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('carRental', carRentalSchema);    @Sasha ---this is the model file code